# Coloring regions in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code for tikz

```
   \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \ang/\col in {0/blue,1/white,2/blue,3/white} {
       \fill[\col!20] (90+90*\ang:2.8)--(0,0)--(63+90*\ang+90:2.8)--cycle;
    }
\draw[thick,->] (0,-2)--(0,2) node[anchor=south east] {$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (-2,0)--(2,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw[magenta,thick] (-2,-2)--(2,2) node[anchor=north west] {Q};
\draw[magenta,thick] (2,-2)--(-2,2) node[anchor=north east] {Q'};
\draw (-1,-2)--(1,2) node[anchor=north west] {$A$};
\draw[] (0,0)--(2,-1) node[anchor=west] {};
\draw[] (0,0)--(-2,1) node[anchor=north ] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

which reproduces the picture below. [image]

**My question is how can I add color to the region enclosed between Q and $y$ in the first quadradant as well as its mirror in the 3rd quadradant?**

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}   

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!20]  (0,2.8) coordinate (a)
                        -- ++ (0,-5.6) 
                        coordinate (b) 
                        -- (-26.5:2.8) -- (153.5:2.8) -- cycle; 
\fill[red!20]   (2,2.0) coordinate (q1)
                        -- (a) --  (b) -- 
                (-2,-2) coordinate (q2)
                        -- cycle;
\draw[thick,->] (0,-2)--(0,2) node[above right] {$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (-2,0)--(2,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[magenta,thick] (q2)--(q1) node[below right] {Q};
\draw[magenta,thick] (2,-2)--(-2,2) node[below left] {Q'};
\draw (-1,-2)--(1,2) node[below right] {$A$};
\draw (0,0) --(2,-1);
\draw (0,0) --(-2,1) node[below] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you like to have?

**Edit:**
The above MWE doesn't differ much from your MWE, acctually I added only red filed region. Difference is only in drawing of `\fill` regions. For them I didn't use `\foreach` loop. For this simple filled shapes is simpler to draw them directly. This also enable to simple definitions of coordinates at blue region for drawing (on similar way) the red one. Coordinates `q1` and `q2` are used only for Q line for which also absolute coordinate can be used.

**Edit (2):** 
In drawing are used relative positioning of coordinates by `-- ++ (...)`, which means that value in parenthesis is distance from previous coordinate (as means `-- + (...)` distance form coordinate `(0,0)`). More details are described in TikZ & PGF Manual, for start read III part: TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm.

As example, how the blue shaded area is drawn:

```
 \fill[blue!20]  % area with blue!20 fill, no border lines
       (0,2.8) coordinate (a) %starting coordinate (0,2.8) is named as coordinate a
 -- ++ (0,-5.6) coordinate (b) % next coordinate lie 0 cm in horizontal direction 
                         % and -5,6 cm in vertical direction from precious coordinate
                         % and it is named as coordinate b                       
-- (-26.5:2.8)           % absolute coordinate, determined with polar coordinates:
                         % angle: -26.5 degree, distance 2.8 cm from (0,0)
-- (153.5:2.8)           % absolute coordinate, determined with polar coordinates:
-- cycle;                % close the path
```

Coordinates a and b are latter used in drawing blue area.

Comment: Hi yes, thanks a lot. Do you mind explaining to me your code? For example if I need to interchange the pink with the white areas.

Comment: @Marion, see edited answer. Inspection of my MWE should show, that it not differ much from yours :)

Comment: how do you exactly work with coordinates though? Which change would enable me to color blue the regions that are white now and the color white the blue ones for example? If you could explain the part that rads as --++(0,-5.6) etc

Comment: @Marion, I add some explanation regarding your above comment. If you like to have one more shaded region, than you can draw them as it shown for blue and red one in MWE. You only need to determine coordinates of path which encounter shaded area. Similarly as I do for the red one.